# list all the documents from a directory with their correspondent folders in R

Tags: r, list, directory

I have to create a list of all the documents from a specific directory.
It is made by 352 folders and every folder has got several documents.

the output that I want is a data frame made by two column: the first one with all the documents and the second one made by the folder to which they belong to.

example : three folders (A, B, C) in a directory.

A is made by c, d, e; 
B is made by f, g, h; 
C is made by l, m, n

so the result will be

```
  File  PF
   c    A
   d    A 
   e    A
   f    B
   g    B
   h    B
   i    C
   l    C
   m    C
```

How could I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code below

```
files <- list.files(recursive = T)
dt <- data.frame(PF = dirname(files), File = basename(files))
```